# Minecraft gives 'Unable to update the Minecraft Native Launcher' when updating to v1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

Minecraft was working perfectly fine until I tried updating to the new 1.9 update. It appears to finish the update but then it pops up a message:

> Unable to update the Minecraft Native Launcher.

Here is a screenshot showing the error:
[image: Unable to update]

I looked around on the Internet and found no support for my problem so I decided to try this website.

I recently updated my computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I believe that this may be related to the problem but I don't know how to fix it without reverting to Windows 7.

Please help me with either updating or reverting back to a previous version of Minecraft, as I don't really care about this update and will probably not use it. I prefer to play on Minecraft 1.7.10 because it has a lot more mods for it.

Comment: Another option (sorry I don't have enough rep to post an answer) is to delete your %APPDATA%/.minecraft folder and then re-install the normal .msi (or "repair" using the .msi)

Comment: Just ran into this (again) today on an old windows 7 laptop.  doing full "windows update" seemed to fix it FWIW, maybe could help after an update to windows 10?

Answer (score 5):

I there is a version of Minecraft that is made for new Windows.  To get it you go to the official website at https://minecraft.net/en/download/. When you go there you can find a link that says:

> Try an alternative download.

On the page that opens you should see a link named Minecraft.exe. Just click that, then it will download and you should be all good.

Here is a screenshot of the download link:

[image: Screenshot of link]

As far as I can tell I am the only person who did not get the new launcher for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's Java, I just fixed that problem.

Uninstall old versions of Java (you can get the uninstaller from their website) and then install the new version. The updater then works fine.