# My Minecraft Wont Launch (MAC)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to open my Minecraft it keeps on showing this text box that says "Downloading Runtime" And When That's Done another text box comes up saying "Unable To Update The Minecraft Native Launcher". I tried re-downloading it several times but the same thing happened. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds like a serverside error. can you post the NativeLog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft gives 'Unable to update the Minecraft Native Launcher' when updating to v1.9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257298/minecraft-gives-unable-to-update-the-minecraft-native-launcher-when-updating-t)

Answer (score 1):

What you could try to do is:

- As Crowley Astray said, post the NativeLog here
- Reinstall Minecraft - as in completely. Back up your maps, then remove every folder and file you can find, then re-download it from the MC website.
- Disable your AV
- See if it's not blocked in your firewall
- Try contacting Mojang (Minecraft Support)

Answer (score -2):

I might have had the same problem. Try to install the .exe version, or the older .exe version.